# Python - Check if column contains value in list, return value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df:

```
d = {'id': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
      'text': ['bill did this', 'jim did something', 'phil', 'bill did nothing',
               'carl was here', 'this is random', 'other name',
               'other bill', 'bill and carl', 'last one']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

And I would like to check if a column contains a value in a list, where the list is:

```
list = ['bill','carl']
```

I'd like to return something like this then

```
id  text                    contains
1   bill did this           bill
2   jim did something       
3   phil                
4   bill did nothing        bill
5   carl was here           carl
6   this is random
7   other name
8   other bill              bill
9   bill and carl           bill
9   bill and carl           carl
10  last one
```

Although the way to handle 2 or more names in the same row is open to change. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: How do you decide bill or carl, if you have both? `is open to change`: what does this mean precisely?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a lambda function to check for every item in your list:

```
d = {'id': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
      'text': ['bill did this', 'jim did something', 'phil', 'bill did nothing',
               'carl was here', 'this is random', 'other name',
               'other bill', 'bill and carl', 'last one']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

l = ['bill','carl']

df['contains'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: ','.join([i for i in l if i in x]))
```

You can remove join if you want the list, else it will just concatenate the values separated by a comma.

**Output**

```
>>df['contains']

0         bill
1             
2             
3         bill
4         carl
5             
6             
7         bill
8    bill,carl
9             
Name: contains, dtype: object
```